# Sublime 3 регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для Sublime 3.
Задача: Удалить все символы между "#" и ":::"
Пример: #Привет:::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `(?<=#).+?(?=:::)`, заменить на пустую строку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

И если можно ещё, как из одно списка прокси, вставить их между "#" ":::"

Пример: 
1 список
5.9.56.112:3128
173.249.24.52:8080
192.121.232.96:80
78.85.163.31:8081

2 список
#:::
#:::
#:::
#:::

Задача: взять прокси из первого списка и поставить их между "#" ":::" в большом количестве
Спасибо

Comment: Лучше вам задать новый вопрос и подробнее расписать ситуацию: в одном ли файле эти списки, если да — что между ними, равно ли количество адресов и сочетаний #:::, не достаточно ли просто обернуть адреса в #:::. Возможно, регуляркой тут не обойдёшься и нужно будет писать скрипт.